# How to tell if navbar is collapsed or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I have a navbar:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button id="toggle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="Gibbs.html"><span><strong>ABOUT</strong></span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>NEWS</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>LAB MEMBERS</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>RESEARCH</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="publications.html"><span>PUBLICATIONS</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>OPPORTUNITIES</span></a>
          </li>
      </ul>    
  </div>
</nav>
```

When the navbar is collapsed (i.e. not expanded), I would like to style other elements on the page.  Is there a simple way in JavaScript that can tell when the navbar is collapsed vs. not collapsed?  Tried this:

```
if ($('#toggle').attr('aria-expanded') == "true") {
  console.log("true")
  }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `if( $(#navbarNav').is(':hidden') )`

Comment: listen for the bootstrap events

Comment: Bootstrap adds a class when you collapse the navbar, right? You might try to check the class with javascript (if it exists or not).

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it works. You are probably having trouble firing the test or your toggle button does not have the mentioned id (toggle).

### Firing the event (on click)

Capture all clicks with:

```
window.onclick = function(e) { ... };
```

### Alternative to your test

Just good old Vanilla JS:

```
if (!document.getElementById('toggle').classList.contains('collapsed')) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [collapse events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events):

```js
$('#navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('not collapsed');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('collapsed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button id="toggle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="Gibbs.html"><span><strong>ABOUT</strong></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>NEWS</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>LAB MEMBERS</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>RESEARCH</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="publications.html"><span>PUBLICATIONS</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>OPPORTUNITIES</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```